# elif: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I want to `re.search` within an if statement but regardless of identation, get syntax error. Is it because `elif:` has no condition?

```
    fr = re.compile(r'(long_regex)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    fra = fr.search(text)
    if fra:
        result = fra.group(5)
    elif:
        f3 = re.compile(r'(some_regex_1)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
        fr3 = f3.search(text)
        result = fr3.group(5)
    elif:
        f4 = re.compile(r'(some_regex)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
        fr4 = f4.search(text)
        result = fr4.group(4)
    else:
        result = None
```

error message

```
  Input In [102]
    elif:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: *elif* what? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `elif` you have `if`, it requires a condition and you provide none, it should be

```
if condition1:
    pass
elif condition2:
    pass
```

---

Using walrus operator (since py3.8) you can improve your code to look like

```
if fra := re.search(r'(long_regex)', text, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
    result = fra.group(5)
elif fr3 := re.search(r'(some_regex_1)', text, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
    result = fr3.group(5)
elif fr4 := re.search(r'(some_regex)', text, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
    result = fr4.group(4)
else:
    result = None
```

If the code is executed multiple times, it should be better to compile the regex onces

Define the compiled regex globally in the file

```
F2 = re.compile(r'(long_regex)', flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
F3 = re.compile(r'(some_regex_1)', flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
F4 = re.compile(r'(some_regex)', flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

Then use it in your methods

```
if fra := F2.search(text):
    result = fra.group(5)
elif fr3 := F3.search(text):
    result = fr3.group(5)
elif fr4 := F4.search(text):
    result = fr4.group(4)
else:
    result = None
```

Answer (score 0):

For elif statement you must provide the condition. For example:

```
if a == 1:
  do_a()
elif a == 2:
  do_b()
else:
  do_c()
```

Comment: Thanks, i guessed it. How could the condition look like here? `elif: fra == None`

Comment: @id345678 `elif fra is None:`

Comment: perfect, thanks guys :)